# php 7.4, ssh_connect(), "Unable to exchange encryption keys" when connecting to ubuntu 22.04 machines

Tags: server, ssh, 22.04, encryption, php7

When using ssh2_connect

```
ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->sshPort)
```

to connect to a server running Ubuntu 22.04
I get the following error on the client

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys in /root/ssh.php on line 175
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to xxx.xxx.com in /root/ssh.php on line 175
```

I get the following error in the Server auth.log

```
Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.xx port 45574: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
```

I found another thread
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408005/php-7-4-ssh-connect-unable-to-exchange-encryption-keys-only-when-connectin) That asked me to do this, along with other things. No luck at all

```
ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->sshPort , [ 'hostkey' => 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-rsa'])
```

I get same error on the client and the following error on the server

```
Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.xx port 53942: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa [preauth]
```

It looks like ssh2_connect only allows ssh-rsa and ssh-dss.

Has anyone got a solution to allow ssh2_connect to connect to a ubuntu server running 22.04

Cheers

Comment: Where are you getting PHP 7.4 from on 22.04?  22.04 does not have PHP 7.4 by default.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 20, rsa wont work anymore, but ecdsa will.

Have you actually created the new keys using ecdsa

From that error message, it doesn't sound like it can find the ecdsa keys.  In particular, on the host server you are trying to connect to

"no matching host key type found"

If you have, do they have the right permissions?

Have you also tried updating the repo:
(I am using libssh2-1)

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal 
main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install libssh2-1
```

Comment: Hiya, sorry for the delay in getting back. I have updated now i am getting
"ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys" Any ideas?